# When to use a preceding slash in path names? (e.g. for the 'cd' command)

Tags: command-line, paths

I am a novice user and I am trying to install Oracle Java. The process calls for me to access `/usr/local/java`, but here is the problem. I get as far as `/usr/local`, then this is the message I get:

```
leonard@leonard-MT6452:/usr/local$ dir
bin  etc  games  include  java  lib  man  sbin  share  src

leonard@leonard-MT6452:/usr/local$ cd /java/
bash: cd: /java/: No such file or directory

leonard@leonard-MT6452:/usr/local$ rm -r ~/java
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/leonard/java’: No such file or directory
```

Help?

Comment: The curly line actually points to your home directory.  You tried removing a java directory from your home directory

Comment: In /java/ first slash means root dir. But in / there is no java folder

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways a path can be specified.

### Absolute paths

Absolute paths always start with a `/`. This means the starting point of the path specification is fixed. No matter where your *current* location is, an absolute path will always point to the same location. The only exception is when you use a shell shortcut, such as `~`, at the start, where the shell will replace `~` with what is usually the *absolute* path of your home directory. Even though it doesn't look like `~/bin` starts with a `/`, when the shell presents its final form, it will have a leading `/`.

### Relative paths

Relative paths never start with `/`. Their starting point is the current directory, so where you end up depends on where you start. They may start with any subdirectory. In addition:

- You can use `.` and `..` to refer to the current directory and the parent directory. You can also use these *within* absolute paths, just not at the start (`/foo/../bar` is the same as `/bar`, and both are absolute paths, but `../foo` is not absolute).
- You can use a setting (environment variable) called `CDPATH` (usually unset), specifically for the `cd` command. If you add a directory to `CDPATH`, then you can use a relative path (not starting with `.` or `..`) to it from anywhere with `cd`.

---

To summarize:

- `cd /usr/local/java` will always take you to the same spot, as does `cd /usr/local/./java`.
- `cd java` will take you different places depending on where you are and what `CDPATH` contains. (Note that only `cd` should be affected by `CDPATH` - for other commands, `./java` and `java` should mean the same thing.)
- `cd ./java` will take you to the directory named `java` within the current directory.
- `cd ../java` will take you to the directory named `java` within the parent directory.
- `cd ~/java` will always take you to the directory named `java` in your home directory. In this case, the path is absolute, but because the shell expands the `~` before `cd` operates on it, different users will end up at different places.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the initial `/` while at `/usr/local/` to go to `/usr/local/java`. The correct command using relative pathname:

```
leonard@leonard-MT6452:/usr/local$ cd java/
leonard@leonard-MT6452:/usr/local/java$ pwd
/usr/local/java
```

You can also take help of `bash_completion` by just typing `cd j` (provided there is no other directory started with `j`) and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, `cd java/` will be printed.

Additionally you can use the absolute path from anywhere:

```
cd /usr/local/java
```

The `/` at the start of a file path always refers the root directory of the [file system hierarchy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview). As there is no file named `/java` you were getting `/java/: No such file or directory` error message.