# How do I direct a file to be stored in a different folder?

Tags: command-line, paths, ls, redirect, filename

So I'm trying to direct a file to be created in another folder (let's say on my Desktop) from my `bin` directory. I made a text file with all the files in the directory using `ls > textfile` but this only creates the file in the `bin` directory, and so I'd like to know how I would direct it to the Desktop straight from `bin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify a path:

```
ls > ~/Desktop/textfile
```

- `~` is your home directory
- `/` separates components in the path
- so to point to something inside your home directory, say `baz` instead in `bar` inside `foo`, you do `~/foo/bar/baz`.

Also see:

- [When to use a preceding slash in path names? (e.g. for the 'cd' command)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607413/when-to-use-a-preceding-slash-in-path-names-e-g-for-the-cd-command/)

Answer (score 1):

Just put `ls > path/to/your/desktop/textfile`. A file named `textfile` will be created in your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by

```
ls > ~/Desktop/textfile
```