# why when i enter to the directory /ok/oky the cmd ls -l test1.txt work why it does'nt work directly "ls -l /ok/oky/test1.txt

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, permissions, directory

Ubuntu server 20.04 TLS
Q: why when i enter to the directory /ok/oky the cmd ls -l test1.txt work why it does'nt work directly "ls -l  /ok/oky/test1.txt[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTxDn.png)

Comment: Because `/ok/` and `ok/` aren't the same. Try `ls -l ok/oky/test1.txt`.

Comment: ah bro it's work thanks for the info

Comment: ... see [When to use a preceding slash in path names? (e.g. for the 'cd' command)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607413/when-to-use-a-preceding-slash-in-path-names-e-g-for-the-cd-command)

Answer (score 0):

`ls -l /ok/oky/test1.txt` references to file starting from root "`/`" directory, aka absolute path. This file seems to not exist.

With `cd ok/oky`, you are changing directory relative to your current directory, aka relative path. You can tell the current directory with command `pwd`.

To correct your first command, you should use: `ls -l ok/oky/test1.txt`

Learn more about relative and absolute paths:
https://linuxhandbook.com/absolute-vs-relative-path/